# Trouble adding an iterator value to map as int

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I figured that I can't covert iterator to int and add it into a map. But I can't figured out any alternative way that I can add the value into my map because I need to keep count of misspelled words in a text file compared to a given dictionary. The iterator is what I need to keep track of the occurance(s). Could someone help me figure out another way to write this? I know it is a bit confusing

```
map<string, int> misspelled;

//Search for matches in random text file
while (getline(random, str)) {
//Search for matched words using regex_search and the rules are already defined 
    while (regex_search(str, matches, rules)) {
        str = matches.suffix().str(); //Assign string to the matched words
        // if words arent in dict - it is misspelled so add it into the map
        if (dict.find(str) != dict.end()){
            // add to map
            misspelled.insert((pair<string, int>(str, dict.find(str)))); //error

        }
        // print out map

    }

}
```

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'pair<std::string, int>' (aka 'pair<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>, int>')

This is the error I got, I figured it was because of the `dict.find(str)` since the `find()` method returns an `iterator`.

Comment: *I can't covert iterator to int and add it into a map.* How have you diagnosed it, got some, what error?

Comment: No matching constructor for initialization of 'pair<std::string, int>' (aka 'pair<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>, int>'). This is the error I got, I figured it was because of the dict.find(str) since set find() function returns an iterator.

Comment: Please add the error to the question. When you got that error, I suppose you tried to google it? Other users can google it too and find your question with a useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the iterator to get its value. Also, after c++ 17 you can use an initialization statement inside the if, so you don't need to call `find()` twice:

```cpp
if (auto item = dict.find(str); item != dict.end()){
    misspelled.insert((pair<string, int>(str, *item))); 
}
```

Comment: I'm using c++ 14, and I just tried that but I dereferenced the iterator outside of the if and still got the same error for some reason.

Comment: Prior to C++17, you can still avoid the double-call by simply storing the iterator in a local variable, eg: `auto iter = dict.find(str); if (iter != dict.end()){ misspelled.insert(make_pair(str, *iter)); }` Also note that I'm using `std::make_pair()` instead of calling the `std::pair<>` constructor directly. Alternatively, you can use `map::operator[]` instead of `map::insert()`, eg: `misspelled[str] = *iter;`